# Crunching lots of data in MySQL - How many rows to select at once?

Tags: mysql, multithreading, performance, algorithm

I have a MySQL table with maybe 800,000 rows that fit the criteria I want to evaluate.  I want to process each row of such data.

I have an algorithm like this:

```
offset = 0 
while offset < 800000
  rows = tbl.query("SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COND1 AND COND2 LIMIT#{offset},10")
  process_rows(rows)
  offset = offset + 10 
end
```

Then I changed it to this, and it ran much faster:

```
offset = 0 
while offset < 800000
  rows = tbl.query("SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COND1 AND COND2 LIMIT#{offset},100")
  process_rows(rows)
  offset = offset + 100 
end
```

*You'll notice here, I am grabbing 100 rows at a time.*

When I say the second example ran much faster, what I am ultimately looking to measure is rows processed per second.

Using a theoretic and practical approach, how can I optimize rows processed per second, the speed of my data processing?  I'd also be willing to use a parallel programming approach (multiple instances or threads).

Comment: What happens if you select 1000 at once? 10000? All 800000?

Comment: We need more information and a less broad question. What is your benchmark testing showing you for processing the various sized chunks? Use that information to figure out your optimal limits. Can you offload processing to the DBM? It'll run circles around retrieving a number of rows and processing in Ruby. Multiple threads won't speed up processing if you're waiting on the database or threads are stepping on each other.

Comment: `LIMIT 100` won't finish just 10 times as fast as `LIMIT 10`, it will finish 100 (10*10) times as fast.  But, it could take months to finish even with "100". See my Answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO!  If you have 800,000 rows, and do $offs, 100, you will end up scanning about 6,400,000,000 rows!  Let me explain...

First time:  LIMIT 0, 100 -- 100 rows needed
Second time:  LIMIT 100, 100 -- 200 rows needed (100 skipped, 100 used)
Third time:  LIMIT 200, 100 -- 300 rows
...
Last time:  LIMIT 799900, 100 -- all 800000 rows are touched.

That adds up to over 6 billion.  The complexity is called O(N*N).

Instead...

Use the `PRIMARY KEY` and remember where you left off.  In my blog, I go into details, even about handling the cases where the PRIMARY KEY is not numeric or has holes in the numbers.  The bottom line:  Only 800,000 rows touched.  This is called O(N).

My blog is aimed at deleting lots of rows; you need the part that talks about "chunking".